# supervisord stop/start all process but exclude X and Y processes

Tags: python, distributed, supervisord, xmlrpclib

I'm trying to stop about 20 services running on a remote server managed by Supervisord in one XMLRPC call.

However, I want to exclude certain processes from it, it would be great if I could do something along the lines of:

```
stopAllProcesses(exclude=["monitorapp","nagios"])
```

Alternatively, I do have a list of all the processes available to me so even doing something like the below is better than actually stopping ALL services or doing 20 individual calls:

```
stopProcess(["process1","process2","process3"])
```

which is much better than doing:

```
stopProcess("process1")
stopProcess("process2")
stopProcess("process3")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The XML-RPC server in `supervisord` supports the [`system.multicall()` endpoint](http://mirrors.talideon.com/articles/multicall.html). Use that to send a *group* of `stopProcess` calls, using the [`MultiCall` XML-RPC proxy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#xmlrpclib.MultiCall):

```
multicall = xmlrpclib.MultiCall(serverproxy)
for proc in procs:
    if proc in exclude:
        continue
    multicall.supervisor.stopProcess(proc)
res = multicall()
```

where `serverproxy` is your XML-RPC proxy to the `supervisord` server. The calls will be sent as one HTTP request and processed on the server in series, being no faster or slower than `stopAllProcesses()`; the latter internally calls `stopProcess` for each process found anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response - definitely getting there, I'm getting a {'results': [{'faultCode': 1, 'faultString': "<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>:'stopProcess'"}]} - doesn't seem to like the 'stopProcess' bit

Comment: @user1741694: Does simply calling `stopProcess()` through XML-RPC work at all for you?

Comment: @user1741694: ah, I suspect the namespace needs to be included; `multicall.supervisor.stopProcess(proc)` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

you have a list of all process names:

```
procs = ['monitorapp', 'nagios', 'process1', 'process2', 'process3']
```

and a list of process names to exclude:

```
exclude = ['monitorapp', 'nagios']
```

you can call them, one at a time...

this will make a call to 'stopProcess()' for each process that is not in the exclude list:

```
stop_procs = [p for p in procs if p not in exclude]
for proc in stop_procs:
    stopProcess(proc)
```

better would be to refactor the API (if possible) to handle a list of processes in one call with include/exclude.

Comment: This is what I was trying to get away from as I could potentially have 100 processes and therefore would need to make 100 calls - not ideal. I found a method called multicall(calls) - but I'm still trying to figure out how to use it...